# Scripting fn key with other key combinations in applescript

Tags: applescript

I am looking for help in scripting the below combination of keys in apple script.

I tried key code {63,123} and other options from previous posts. But none is helpful. Also I am doing this on a MacBook. Would the key codes differ from MacBook to Macbook Pro?

```
“fn + left arrow”
“fn + right arrow”
“fn + up arrow”
“fn + down arrow”
```

Answer (score 0):

On my keyBoard, I have the following mapping :

fn+left = pageup key = diagonal arrow (bottom right to top left) = key code 116

fn+right = pagedown key = diagonal arrow (top left to bottom right) = key code 121

fn+up = home key = key code 115

fn+down = end key = key code 119

I also tried on small wireless keyboard and get the same.I can't test on MCBPro